# How to remove core macOS keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard

Mac OS comes loaded with some shortcuts to modify text. Can these be removed?

Thank you!

```
Control-A: Move to the beginning of the line or paragraph.
Control-E: Move to the end of a line or paragraph.
Control-F: Move one character forward.
Control-B: Move one character backward.
Control-L: Center the cursor or selection in the visible area.
Control-P: Move up one line.
Control-N: Move down one line.
Control-O: Insert a new line after the insertion point.
Control-T: Swap the character behind the insertion point with the character in front of the insertion point.
```

Why do I want these? — I would like to have these options for programs in Terminal—which I currently can't use because my Mac will hijack these particular keys.

https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201236

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), so can you describe in more details which problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @nohillside — I added my reasons.

Comment: @nohillside — Discovered the program that was hijacking my keyboard. It wasn't obvious but now problem is solved :)

Comment: Great you solved the issue. Could you add an answer providing information on the app that was causing this behavior and how to solve it? This will help others and you can then mark your answer as accepted.